# Disassembly of bin-file with Ghridra

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, bin, ghidra

Im having an issue. 
I have a bin file that i want to disassemble.
The processor is a Intel Atom® x5-Z8350.
Im using Ghidra but im not sure what language I should choose when disassembling this.
Any experts that could get me a bit further in this.

If there is any questions please let me know, and i'll do my best to answer them :)

Comment: This processor supports both the IA32 and IA64 instruction sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **binwalk** to analyze bin files to see if there is any information

good luck!!!!

Comment: Can you add some extra info or maybe a sample, the user might need some additional text to better understand the answer